# Django and MySQL utf8 encoding issue

Tags: django, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a database that uses a UTF-8 charset encoding. When I use the shell prompt to run mysql and select rows from tables, I can see the characters just fine (`Frédéric Bélier`). However, when running my django project and viewing a page in browser the field shows up as `FrÃ©dÃ©ric BÃ©lier`. The HTML page as a charset meta tag of UTF-8.

When opening my views file (and template file) in Gedit I see that the charset is set to UTF-8 as well. However, when I run `file -i views.py` the output is `views.py: text/x-java; charset=us-ascii / ASCII Java program text, with CRLF line terminators`.

Any advices on what can be wrong and how it can be fixed?

Comment: Did you check your settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET?

Comment: does adding "# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-" change anything?

Comment: Django+MySQL: How To Fix Unicode (aka Mysterious Question Marks) - Standard Deviations -> http://parand.com/say/index.php/2008/06/11/djangomysql-how-to-fix-unicode-aka-mysterious-question-marks/

Comment: I don't think that the encoding of your *.py files has anything to with it.

Comment: settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET is set to utf-8 and I tried adding "# -- coding: utf-8 --", with not much success... 
@Efazati - I already have these settings configured correctly as shown in that post.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a Django expert but perhaps it has something to do with a

1. HTTP Header or Document Header
2. A Django configuration. In Python a string is not necessarily unicode (unlike .NET for example)

My gut tells me that 2 in the probable situation.